Comparing and updating changes - SQL
I have 2 tables: latest and history. History will have all the rows loaded before and latest will have latest data in it. I want to come up with a consolidated table based on load_date and the table should indicate when the change was made.
Latest table:
 id   col1 col2 load_date
1001    a   g   1/3/2024
1003    q   r   1/3/2024

History table:
id    col1 col2 load_date
1001    a   b   1/1/2024
1002    d   e   1/1/2024
1001    a   g   1/2/2024

I would like my consolidated table to be like:
id     col1 col2 load_date  change
1001    a   b    1/1/2024   new entry
1001    a   g    1/2/2024   col2 changed
1001    a   g    1/3/2024   
1002    d   e    1/1/2024   new entry
1002    d   e    1/2/2024   no show
1003    q   r    1/3/2024   new entry

I am having trouble in tracking the changes and update against specific date. Particularly, which date the id showed up and which date the id last showed up.
Below is what i have tried:
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=5d406760-006a-4acb-9c96-e3a5236b1209
code:
create table latest(id int, col1 varchar, col2 varchar, load_date date);

        insert into latest 
        values(1001,'a','g','1/3/2024'),
              (1003,'q','r','1/3/2024');--newly showed up on 1/3

        --select * from latest;
        
        create table history(id int, col1 varchar, col2 varchar, load_date date);

        insert into history 
        values
        (1001,'a','b','1/1/2024'),
        (1002,'d','e','1/1/2024'),
        (1001,'a','g','1/2/2024');--colb changed on 1/2
        --(1002,'d','e','1/2/2024')--did not show up
        --select * from history;
        
        with combined as
     (
     select *,'latest' as source from latest l
     union all
     select *, 'history' as source from history h
     ),
     
    changes AS (
        SELECT
            ct1.id,
            ct1.col1,
            ct1.col2,
            ct1.load_date,
            CASE
                WHEN ct1.col1 <> ct2.col1 THEN 'col1 changed'
                WHEN ct1.col2 <> ct2.col2 THEN 'col2 changed'
                ELSE NULL
            END AS changes
        FROM
            combined ct1
            LEFT JOIN combined ct2
            ON ct1.id = ct2.id
    )

select * from changes

Can I get some help to solve this please?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

thanks. I'll modify.but for sharing what i tried, i added a fiddler too.

The code should be here as well. We shouldn't have to leave the site to get information needed for your post. Also, images of data are useless because they can't be copied and pasted to create data to use for testing solutions to your problem. You should post the DDL to create the tables and the DML to populate them, along with the SQL you've tried using. See [mre] and [ask], as well as Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

You might want a Ledger table. SQL Server has this builtin.

Modified as persuggestions

Why did 1002 disappear?

that id stopped after 1/2. that;s why.

first you union both table and then use window function lag() to get the previous row value. And to get the final change, use case expression to compare current with previous row value.
To handle the "no show", use the latest row from history and check with latest. This logic is handle in the last section of the union query
with cte as
(
  select id, col1, col2, load_date, change = null
  from   latest
  union all
  select id, col1, col2, load_date, change = null
  from   history
  union all
  select id, col1, col2, load_date = dateadd(day, 1, load_date),
         change = 'no show'
  from   (
             select id, col1, col2, load_date,
                    rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by load_date desc)
             from history 
         ) h
  where  h.rn = 1
  and    not exists
         (
             select *
             from   latest x
             where  x.id = h.id
         )
),
cte2 as
(  
  select id, col1, col2, load_date, change, 
         prev_col1 = lag(col1) over (partition by id order by load_date),
         prev_col2 = lag(col2) over (partition by id order by load_date)  
  from   cte
)
select *,
       change = isnull(change, '')
              + case when prev_col1 is null and prev_col2 is null
                     then 'new entry'
                     else ''
                     end
              + case when prev_col1 <> col1 
                     then 'col1 changed '
                     else ''
                     end
              + case when prev_col2 <> col2 
                     then 'col2 changed '
                     else ''
                     end  
from   cte2
order by id, load_date

db<>fiddle demo

Lots of ways to approach this. Here I've just stuck to simple unions. Since you'll need to look back to prior rows I figure the easiest way to find the no shows is just to grab the last src value at the same time. Once all the data is pooled together the change can be as verbose as necessary and all that logic is contained within a specific area of code. Depending on the size of your data there might be significant variance in query performance across the different answers.
with combined as (
    select id, col1, col2, load_date, 'L' as src from latest
    union all
    select id, col1, col2, load_date, 'H' as src from history
), staggered as (
    select *,
        first_value(src) over (partition by id order by load_date desc) as last_src,
        lead(col1) over (partition by id order by load_date desc) as prior_col1,
        lead(col2) over (partition by id order by load_date desc) as prior_col2
    from combined    
), fullhistory as (
    select id, col1, col2, prior_col1, prior_col2, load_date, src
    from staggered
    union all
    select id, col1, col2, prior_col1, prior_col2, dateadd(day, 1, last_load), 'N'
    from staggered
    where last_src = 'H'
)
select id, col1, col2, load_date,
    case when prior_col1 is null then 'new entry'
         when src = 'N' then 'no show'
         when col1  = prior_col1 and col2  = prior_col2 then 'no change'
         when col1 <> prior_col1 and col2 <> prior_col2 then 'col1 & col2 changed'
         when col1 <> prior_col1 then 'col1 changed'
         when col2 <> prior_col2 then 'col2 changed'
    end as change
from fullhistory
order by id, load_date;

I've made the assumption that your values can't be null. If that proves to be untrue then adjust some of the comparisons accordingly.

Using your data:
SELECT  final.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  ct1.id
        ,   ct1.col1
        ,   ct1.col2
        ,   ct1.load_date
        ,   ct1.source
        ,   LAG(ct1.col1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY load_date, source) AS prevCol1
        ,   LAG(ct1.col2) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY load_date, source) AS prevCol2
        ,   LEAD(ct1.source) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY load_date, source) AS nextSource
        FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            ,   'latest' AS source
            FROM    latest l
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  *
            ,   'history' AS source
            FROM    history h
             ) ct1
    ) combined
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  id, col1, col2, load_date
        ,   CONCAT_WS(', ', CASE WHEN prevCol1 IS NULL THEN 'new entry' END, CASE WHEN prevCol1 <> col1 THEN 'col1 changed' END, CASE WHEN prevCol2 <> col2 THEN 'col2 changed' END) AS changes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, col1, col2, dateadd(day, 1, load_date), 'no entry'
        WHERE   nextsource IS NULL
        AND source = 'history'
) final


First, you combine latest and history with help of UNION ALL
Then by using LAG/LEAD you can keep track of both the previous values (to handle changes) and no entry rows
Finally, you take the data and then create a new row using UNION ALL for the entries without upcoming entry (this is the fake no entry row). The CONCAT_WS creates a string with all the change texts, it handles both col1 + col2 changes as well.

